# Using a Random Number in a Drawable Path

Tags: android, random, path, numbers, drawable

I am using a random number to set my imageButton to a random image.  I am wondering if there is a way to use the random int in the file path for the drawable.  This code gives a run time error for invalid integer but will compile.

```
Random generator = new Random();
int chooseFirstPicture = generator.nextInt(2);
int imagePath1 = Integer.parseInt("R.drawable.image" + chooseFirstPicture);
btn1.setBackgroundResource(imagePath1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are parsing a `String` to a `Integer`, so your code is going to throw a `NumberFormatException` every time you run it.

The correct way to get a **resource id** from a String key is using the function `getIdentifier()`:

```
Random generator = new Random();
int chooseFirstPicture = generator.nextInt(2);
int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("image" + chooseFirstPicture, "drawable", getPackageName());
if (resourceId != 0) {
    //Provided resource id exists in "drawable" folder
    btn1.setBackgroundResource(imagePath1);
} else {
    //Provided resource id is not in "drawable" folder.
    //You can set a default image or keep the previous one.
}
```

You can find more information in the Android [Resources class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Hm..  You trying to convert "R.drawable.image1" string to an integer that is impossible. During compilation nothing checks what's in the string, but when you run the app, it fails immediately.

Better to use the getResources().getIdentifier() with proper parameters ([link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29))

I hope it helps :)

Comment: "R.drawable.image1" cannot be converted to an integer? Because the setBackgroundResource() method takes an integer and works when I directly put the image path in its parameters (setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image1)).

Comment: R.drawable.image != "R.drawable.image1"